# Установка языка для отдельного процесса

Tags: java, android, процесс, locale

Есть приложение и несколько файлов `strings.xml` с разными языками.
Пользователь сам выбирает нужный ему язык, а я сохраняю его в `SharedPreferences` и устанавливаю с помощью

```
Locale locale = new Locale(lang);
Locale.setDefault(locale);
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
configuration.locale = locale;
getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(configuration, null);
```

Вот только у меня еще есть `Foreground Service`, который работает в отдельном процессе и на такую "насильную" установку языка ему плевать.

```
<service
        android:name=".Name"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:process=":NameProcc">
</service>
```

Ну и так как он в отдельном процессе, то и доступа `SharedPreferences` у него нет.

Как установить язык для отдельных процессов?

p.s. конечно можно это сделать через `putExtra` но меня интересует, есть ли глобальный способ указать всему приложению язык (не глядя на разные процессы).

Comment: доступ к  SharedPreferences у сервиса есть

Comment: @Style-7 если они в отдельном `android:process`, то он не имеет доступа к SharedPreferences в default процессе. можете сами потестить и убедиться.

Comment: пошлите ему сообщение, в сервисе поставьте приемник

Comment: @Style-7 это уже костыли. меня интересует есть ли нормальное решение.

Comment: как раз это ваше решение костыль

Comment: @Style-7 можете тогда подсказать "как пользователю задать язык приложения отличное от системного" ?

Comment: *не имеет доступа к SharedPreferences в default процессе* - что-то я такого не подозревал, вы именованный преференс используете [`Context.getSharedPreferences (name, mode)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String,%20int))? Ещё есть вариант специально для хранения настроек приложения: `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences()`. Ну или просто в файл записать, наконец.

Comment: @woesss я использую `getSharedPreferences`. можно и не через файл, а тем же `putExtra`. но интересен "как без них, через Locale и Configuration или еще как задать язык для отдельных процессов.

Comment: Никак - задавать надо в самом процессе, соответственно при запуске сервиса надо проверить где-то сохранённую или переданную настройку и применить. Если язык меняется "по ходу пьесы" то ещё и посылать сообщение об изменении сервису, чтобы он обновил настройку. Коммуникация между процессами возможна только через интенты, файлы или сеть.